# How do I use a local Volume for bitnami/cassandra:4.1 without permission errors?

Tags: docker, cassandra, bitnami

I have the following

```
cassandra:   
  container_name: cassandra   
  image: bitnami/cassandra:4.1   
  volumes:     
    - ./cassandra_data:/bitnami   
  environment:     
    - CASSANDRA_SEEDS=cassandra     
    - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD_SEEDER=yes     
    - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD=cassandra
```

But when I run I get

```
2023-10-01 11:26:55 realpath: /bitnami/cassandra/conf: No such file or directory
2023-10-01 11:26:55 mkdir: cannot create directory '/bitnami/cassandra': Permission denied
```

If I remove the volume, everything works fine but that isn't what I want, I want it to store the data on my local box instead of the container.

How do I configure for the proper permissions?

Answer (score 0):

The user runs the process is not usually `root`, which is missing the write permission on `/bitnami/cassandra` I guess.
Try to use root as your user:

```
cassandra:
  user: root
```

Or in Dockerfile:

```
USER 1001
```

Comment: Is there a way to run it as the proper wsl user? That is the person with permissions and I don't really want to use root